# How to run cgi script on apache server

Tags: apache, perl, cgi

This is my program:

```
[root@localhost cgi-bin]# locate first.pl 
/home/Ram/Desktop/work/first.pl
/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/first.pl
[root@localhost cgi-bin]# cd /usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/
[root@localhost cgi-bin]# vi first.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use warnings;
use warnings;
use CGI;
print "content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<h2>Hello, World!</h2>\n";
```

I am calling the script from my browser like this:

> http://localhost/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/first.pl

I didn't get output, but I'm getting an error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/first.pl was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at localhost Port 80

I checked in web browser whether the Apache web server is working or not by using :

> https://localhost

It us showing the welcome page.

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: can you add your virtual host configuration

Comment: no httpd.conf or if your virtual host has a separate config file include it

Comment: Try runnning "chmod 755 /usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/first.pl"

Comment: can you tell me how to see the httpd.conf

Comment: @Mark Setchell in browser???

Comment: `<VirtualHost *:80>
#    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
#    DocumentRoot /www/docs/dummy-host.example.com
#    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
#    ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
#    CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
#</VirtualHost>
`

Answer (score 6):

You basically need to change two files after installing apache2 on linux.

Go to terminal and set the following configs:

1. `sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` and add the follwing:

   ```
   <Files ~ "\.(pl|cgi)$">
       SetHandler perl-script
       PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::PerlRun
       Options +ExecCGI
       PerlSendHeader On
   </Files>
   ```
2. `sudo vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and add the following:

   `<Directory /var/www/cgi-bin/>
       AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
       Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
       AllowOverride None
   </Directory>`

After adding these two config changes, write a perl script, place it in the cgi-bin directory, and then give it sufficient privileges (`sudo chmod 755 <filename>`)

Finally, restart apache2: `sudo apache2ctl restart`

Screenshots:
[image: default.conf]
[image: apache2.conf]

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the above process works but the easy way is:

1. Enable the `CGI- sudo a2enmod cgi`
2. Restart the Apache and it works -service apache2 restart
3. Run the cgi file http://localhost/cgi-bin/1.sh

Best Of Luck !!

Answer (score 0):

In your web configuration (`httpd.conf` or your virtual host configuration file) you should have the following fragment:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /etc/local/apache2/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/etc/local/apache2/cgi-bin">
   Options ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
</Directory>
```

restart the server, don't forget to `chmod +x /usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/first.pl` and then load `http://localhost/cgi-bin/first.pl`

This assumes that either there are no virtual hosts in your config, or that the virtual host you configured is the default one. See the apache docs if needed.

Comment: `ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

#
# "/var/www/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
 ` this is only have

Comment: These `/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` and
`/usr/local/apache2/conf/original/httpd.conf` are only there in machine

Comment: on which one to check httpd.conf? please let me know

Comment: I would think it's `/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`, but in any case, why not try one, and if it doesn't work try the other one?

Comment: `/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf  
 ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>
<IfModule cgid_module>
</IfModule>
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

/usr/local/apache2/conf/original/httpd.conf
  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>
<IfModule cgid_module>
</IfModule>

<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>`

Comment: was there a question hidden in your previous comment? ;--)